# "Invalid object name" when using global temp table in stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, global-temp-tables

I'm following several examples to use `global temp table` such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43529268/2243398) & [this](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1255095-145-1.aspx)

I have following query to get data into a `global temp table`:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = N'SELECT * INTO ##tmpDraftTableData  
             FROM ' + @DraftTableName 

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Note that the `@DraftTableName` is dynamic and come from different table with different structure, that's why I need to use **dynamic query**.

And then I want to insert the data as obtain from above global `temp table` into another temp table to loop and process the data:

```
SELECT *
INTO #tmpDraftTableData
FROM ##tmpDraftTableData  -- ERROR: Invalid object name ##tmpDraftTableData
```

Seems like I can't use the global temp table with the error

> Invalid object name ##tmpDraftTableData

unlike other sample code.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: [I can't reproduce this...](http://rextester.com/FVPYT9464)

Comment: "...into another temp table to loop and process the data". If you know which columns or structure your looping data should have, would you mind considering creating a well-known temporary table and inserting the columns you need from @DraftTableName? If the temporary table is created outside the dynamic SQL, you will be able to select it's contents outside of the dynamic SQL also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE ##tmpDraftTableData (ID INT)
INSERT INTO ##tmpDraftTableData VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO ##tmpDraftTableData VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO ##tmpDraftTableData VALUES(3)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @DraftTableName VARCHAR(100)='##tmpDraftTableData'

SET @SQL = N'SELECT * 
            INTO #tmpDraftTableData  
             FROM ' + @DraftTableName +'

             SELECT * FROM #tmpDraftTableData
             '
```

You can directly execute the query, instead of using `sp_executesql`.

```
PRINT (@SQL)
EXEC (@SQL)
```

**Output:**

```
ID
1
2
3
```